# SUMIFS Producing 0

Tags: excel, sumifs

Excel Screenshot:
[image: Excel Screenshot]

I'm trying to use SUMIFS and I keep getting 0 as the result. From the image linked above, you can see that it should produce 200. What am I doing wrong? Column B is formatted as Number, A, and G are Short Date, and D is Text.

Comment: check that sequence of SUMIF parameters is correct

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski It is.

Comment: the second parameters should be criteria ? https://support.office.com/en-us/article/sumif-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: @KamilKiełczewski - that's SUMIF, this is about SUMIFS.

Comment: My guess is that even though A is formatted as a short date it is in fact a text that resembles a date.

Comment: By all appearances that should work. You might try clearing B2 and retyping the description manually.

Comment: @ScottCraner I'm assuming that the OP has not fiddled with alignment but that date is correctly right-aligned.

Comment: I was going by the fact that the OP stated they are formatted the same yet one is `mm/dd/yyyy` and the other `m/d/yyyy` @Jeeped

Comment: then could the date in A be formatted `dd/mm/yyyy` that would also through it off, and make it right aligned.

Comment: Honestly did not catch that. Perhaps one was typed in as mdy and he other two as dmy but all three are actually dates.

Comment: The data was imported -- so it's possible that the formatting is wonky from that.  When I manually type in the dates in A, the SUMIFS works.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me. Use the INDIRECT function to make it point to the reference G3 rather than its string value.

```
=SUMIFS(B:B,D:D,"BCBS*", A:A,">=" & INDIRECT("G3"), A:A,"<=" & INDIRECT("G4"))
```

Comment: Not only it makes the formula volatile, it also achieves nothing because the concatenation of `">"` and `INDIRECT("G3")` wants the string representation anyway. In particular, it still gives `0` for the OP's data provided it was [formatted as string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49198326/sumifs-producing-0#comment85402014_49198326) in the cell.